# Задача на семафоры Unix

Tags: c, многопоточность, unix, семафоры

> Рассмотрим мост через реку с односторонним движением. Как только перед мостом скапливаются 2 корабля, мост разводится. Необходимо реализовать движение автомобилей/кораблей согласно условиям, используя семафоры и передавая параметры через файл.

Формально я понимаю, что в рамках этой задачи необходимо создать процессы - автомобиль и корабль. Сделать их синхронизацию через семафоры, которые реализованы в Unix в библиотеке . Однако мне прежде не доводилось работать в этой сфере, поэтому нужна сторонняя помощь.

Конкретно, интересно решение задачи, ее методы. Быть может, кто-то сможет поделиться решением аналогичной задачи или конструктивными набросками решения этой, по возможности с кодом.

Comment: Что уже у вас получилось? Добавте ваш код.

Comment: вопрос и заключается в методах, которые можно здесь применить
добавлять мне нечего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предварительно хотел бы заметить, что если Вы попытаетесь реализовать задачу через pthread (man 7 pthreads) и мьютексы/семафоры - головная боль Вам обеспечена. Гораздо проще воспользоваться механизмами синхронизации, уже имеющимися в ОС linux:

1. Каналы (man 7 pipe)
2. Очереди сообщений (man 7 mq_overview)

Реализация задачи, по моему мнению, проще всего выглядит так:

1. Создаём три процесса - корабли, автомобили, диспетчер;
2. Процессы "корабли" и "автомобили" отправляют (со случайными интервалами) сообщения диспетчеру;
3. Диспетчер принимает сообщения и считает их.

Если сообщение пришло от того, кто имеет право проезда, счётчик не увеличивается.

При наступлении указанного условия диспетчер переключает состояние моста и сбрасывает соответствующий счетчик.

Собственно - всё...Очень просто! Именно благодаря тому, что НЕ используются примитивные механизмы синхронизации типа семафоров.

За подробностями  рекомендую: Уильям Стивенс; "Unix. Взаимодействие процессов", главы 4, 5 и 6.

Если строго придерживаться постановки задачи, то реализация (в самом общем виде) может выглядеть как-то так:

1. Главная программа создаёт семафор с помощью *sem_open(.. O_CREAT ..);*
2. Главная программа запускает две нити: корабли и диспетчер;
3. Нить диспетчера повисает на семафоре *sem_wait()*;
4. Нить кораблей выполняет бесконечный цикл: ждёт случайный промежуток времени и поднимает семафор *sem_post()*;
5. Сосокочив с семафора, нить диспетчера наращивает счётчик кораблей. Если счётчик == 2, то диспетчер переключает мост и сбрасывает счётчик.

Кстати, из постановки задачи совершенно не ясно, как быть с возвратом моста в исходное положение.

Это всё я говорил про POSIX семафоры. Можно сделать то же самое с помощью семафоров System-V. Там всё позаковырестей, но - интересней :-)

Последнее замечание. Начиная с POSIX 2001 в стандарте присутствует возможность, чрезвычайно подходящая для Вашей задачи - условные переменные *pthread_cond_init()*. Если любопытно - посмотрите!

Comment: Я согласен с Вами, но задача поставлена именно так, требуется синхронизация через семафоры.

Comment: **задача поставлена именно так** - дописал ответ.